# Integrate Indian Payment Gateway (CCAvenue) in Ruby on Rails e-commerce application supporting by Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, spree, ccavenue

Currently working on an e-commerce web-application. It is being developed by Spree on Ruby on Rails plateform. 
I am not able to integrate any Indian Payment Gateway in this app.

 I tried CCAvenue but getting problem. Even I am not able to find any command for using it.
This is also not working https://github.com/meshbrain/active_merchant_ccavenue

I also tried Paypal but Paypal has stopped its services in India.

---

Please give suggestion quickly as I've less time for integrating it.

Comment: Have you tried Spree/CCAvenue tech support?

Comment: No....not till now....I want comments first who have used Payment Gateways before.
As they can help more.

Comment: Well, you should have done *that* first.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to try this gem if you r using Spree**...

```
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => "1-1-stable" # make sure to include after spree
```